# Can I use the Google font 'Lato' for a logo design?

Tags: fonts, logo, copyright, web-fonts, legal

I am creating a logo and would like to use the Google Font 'Lato', can I use this font in my logo design or are there copyright/limitations I need to worry about? I can't find anything online other than that it is an open source font that can be used in anyway you want (maybe that's my answer but I just want to make sure). Also, is it a bad idea to use a web-based font for a logo?

Comment: You can use it for anything. Also, you can download the non web-based font, [here](http://www.latofonts.com/).

Answer (score 5):

> it is an open source font that can be used in anyway you want

Yep.

It is licensed under the [OFL license](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL).

The key bullet point for your needs is:

- Use: the freedom to use font software for any purpose

So, yes, you can use it in your logo.

> Also, is it a bad idea to use a web-based font for a logo?

It's "web based" in that Google offers it as an embeddable web-font for web sites, but other than that, it's just a font. So there's nothing particularly 'web based' about the design itself.